# How to make a javascript alert with a GEO callout

Tags: javascript

I have this alert box so far.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
alert("Hello users from ");
</script>
```

Also have this GEO code

```
<script>var geo_region=geoip_region_name(); if(geo_region) document.write(geo_region);else document.write(geoip_country_name());</script>
```

I'm wanting to put the GEO code to where the java alert says Hello users from "city". How can I add the script to the alert without it breaking?

JSFiddle to show code: http://jsfiddle.net/r9xwv1sL/1/

Comment: It looks like geo_region is defined in the global space. Put your alert below that script and you should be able to access the var in your script.

Comment: How would I add the vars correctly to this? I don't know how to add the if, else parts to the alert var. 

I know to just call the region it would be 

alert(" Hello users from ' +geo_region+ '")l

Comment: Can you put together a Fiddle with what you currently have? Set it up at http://jsfiddle.net/, save it, and then put the link in your post so we have a reference to what you have. That will make it easier.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r9xwv1sL/

Comment: It looks as though there might be something missing at the bottom of that, as I see a start script tag and no end. Also, I don't see the bit with the GEO code you have in the post. Can you update it?

Comment: Sorry about that! I fixed it I'm pretty sure with everything needed.

Answer (score 0):

Great. That did help. I cleaned up the code a bit and then modified it.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r9xwv1sL/5/

Explanation:

1. HTML loads a document sequentially. This means scripts at the top execute before scripts at the bottom.
2. Any variable defined in the global space is accessible to any script existing below the definition. This means if you define "var myName = 'blah'" in the head, you can have another script in the body that shows "myName". IE: "alert(myName);" in the body.
3. In contrast, variables defined in the scope of a function are only accessible in that scope.

Because the geo_city var is defined globally, you can access it in your alert by moving your alert script after the script setting that var. Then, you just add the var reference to your alert like:

```
alert("\nHello users from " + geo_city + "\n\nPress OK to continue...");
```

That's all I did in the Fiddle :)